# schedule library how to pass an arg in parallel execution

Tags: python

I am experimenting with the schedule library with Python and they have some examples on how to [pass an argument](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#pass-arguments-to-a-job) as shown below in the `greet` function:

```
import schedule

def greet(name):
    print('Hello', name)

schedule.every(2).seconds.do(greet, name='Alice')
schedule.every(4).seconds.do(greet, name='Bob')

from schedule import every, repeat

@repeat(every().second, "World")
@repeat(every().day, "Mars")
def hello(planet):
    print("Hello", planet)
```

This is the example from the repo of how to run use schedule in [parallel execution](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#pass-arguments-to-a-job) that incorporates threading:

```
import threading
import time
import schedule

def job():
    print("I'm running on thread %s" % threading.current_thread())

def run_threaded(job_func):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_func)
    job_thread.start()

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)


while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

How do I combine the two concepts using parallel execution and also passing an argument? This code below is NOT from the repo but myself just experimenting:

```
import threading
import time
import schedule
from schedule import every, repeat

def job(name):
    print("I'm running on thread %s" % threading.current_thread())
    print('Hello', name)

def run_threaded(job_func):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_func)
    job_thread.start()

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, name='Alice')
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, name='Sam')
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, name='Bob')
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, name='Steve')
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, name='Lester')


while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

This will error out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bbartling\OneDrive - Slipstream\Desktop\LBS\openCvTesting\SO_schedules.py", line 24, in <module>
    schedule.run_pending()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 780, in run_pending
    default_scheduler.run_pending()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 100, in run_pending
    self._run_job(job)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 172, in _run_job
    ret = job.run()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 661, in run
    ret = self.job_func()
TypeError: run_threaded() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the arguments to a class and create instances of the class for every thread.

```
import threading
import time
import schedule


class greeting():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def hello(self):
        print("I'm running on thread %s" % threading.current_thread())
        print('Hello', self.name)


def run_threaded(name):
    instance = greeting(name)
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=instance.hello)
    job_thread.start()


schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, name='Alice')
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, name='Sam')
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, name='Bob')
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, name='Steve')
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, name='Lester')


while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I also put in a git issue for this if your on github, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

[`threading.Thread` takes a parameter `args` that passes arguments down to the function.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)

```
import threading
import time
import schedule
from schedule import every, repeat

def job(name):
    print("I'm running on thread %s" % threading.current_thread())
    print('Hello', name)

def run_threaded(job_func, name):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_func, args=(name,))
    job_thread.start()

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, name='Alice')
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, name='Sam')
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, name='Bob')
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, name='Steve')
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, name='Lester')


while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```